# I'm looking for an API, how is this NOT a programming question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Why would they close this: [What is the most popular MMO game that has an out-of-game API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474030/what-is-the-most-popular-mmo-game-that-has-an-out-of-game-api-closed)

Comment: Is "Who is the prettiest Hollywood star whose website is written in PHP?" a programming question?

Comment: You have a point, however, my question is extremely relevant, and a truly interesting question. I would not have to ask it at all if World of Warcraft has an API, yet it fails to have one since its a closed off,isolated game system. Thus, the natural question is, which MMO does have an API. This is a perfectly valid, interesting, and praiseworthy question. The only reason I can currently think of for its closing, is a mere herd mentality has taken the grip of the closers.

Comment: in your opinion.

Comment: I can follow your argument somewhat but I think the majority opinion is going to be that it's off-topic. Maybe ask on gaming.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Pekka No, that's for Gamedev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this question.

1. You are asking for a recommendation. You risk getting answers voted by the popularity of the game, rather than answers voted by the quality of the answer. Those questions don't really work on this engine in general.
2. While it might have technically been on topic on Stack Overflow, it definitely is not on topic on Gaming. Gaming is about, you know, playing games. Development of game-API-consuming programs is not what Gaming covers. *slaps Pekka on fingers*

I'm sorry your experience was subpar.

Comment: Since we've already established that it's *not* a programming question, I'm having trouble understanding how it's on-topic for GameDev... Would balpha's example be on-topic for WebDev?!

Comment: @Shog It's a question about designing and/or writing a tool consuming a game API. If you forget it's a game API, it could almost fit on SO, though it doesn't because five 3kers on SO say it doesn't and the question isn't reopened yet. The next best fit is Gamedev then. (Also, the original question is tagged `game-development`)

Comment: @radp: honestly, I don't see it. He's not asking how to use an API (he did ask if WOW *had* an API in a previous question), or how to design an API, or how to accomplish some game-dev or general programming task... He's just looking for games that support a certain feature. I must assume that gaming.SE would also kick a question on games that support 3D glasses over to hardware.SE, screenshots over to photoshop.SE, and demos over to machinima.SE?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that so many games have closed software ecosystems, and aint that wrong?? So, by getting informed as to what games have the official API's, I assist the world economy in focusing development effort on ecosystems that will benefit more than corporation XYZ.

Comment: @hunterp: and the point we're all trying to make is, this isn't the place to make your point.

Comment: I'm getting very nice traction now that I've found the appropriate niche within the stackexchange world. Stackexchange has definitely been the correct, supportive, and informative place to get an answer from the plethora of generous people. So thank you.

Comment: @Shog As I said, recommendation questions work horribly on the entirety of Stack Exchange. That said, the object of a recommendation is not a game, but a game API. Who's going to be able to recommend one best?

Comment: @radp: gamers who program? Wait, is this a trick question...

Comment: @Shog9 _pulls out bell_ [goood nightahdingdingdingdingdingdingding](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP0sqRMzkwo)?

Comment: Look at how subjective and opinionated this question is... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246550/are-people-really-using-google-app-engine-or-they-are-just-playing-with-it-becau

Comment: @hunterp To be fair, that's [good subjective.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 3):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but... ehhh...

The problem was, your question was not about an API; it was not about how to find documentation for an API; it was not about a problem you had writing code against an API; It was not even about how to find an API for game X...

It was really about the games. Your question was no more on topic than a question about, say, "Which OS should I program for?" would be.

If I had to guess at a site it would be appropriate on, I would guess `programmers` might be the closest match - *but* I don't think it's the kind of question that any SE site really caters toward, IMO.

Comment: **This.** The question was, in essence, a product recommendation request. These are tolerated, to a degree, on *some* SE sites... but there are [very good reasons](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations) not to encourage them.

Comment: @Shog9 I hadn't even considered *this* site; D'oh! And agreed about the question basically being a product recommendation request.

Comment: er, no, I meant... This (your answer) is the answer (IMHO).